# iOS detect when app is closed from the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to detect when a user hits the home button twice to close the app in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's before the application terminates.

}
```

But yes its won't call in background when you close from home button.

For more info please go through doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:

Comment: No, Apple explicitly does not give you any warning at all when closing your app while it's in the background.

Comment: Why downvote my answer?? Can anybody tell me reason of it?

Comment: I already did. It's wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right. It will doesn't call if we close app in background using home button pressed.

Comment: I have read those docs many times. It is quite easily demonstrated that this is false. Create an empty app, in the delegate put log messages in the application state calls. You will see that `WillTerminate` is never called.

Comment: So how can we know when its killed in the background?

Comment: @Alosyius you can't Once it's in the background, it is open for termination without notice at any time.

Comment: If you wonder why this method exists, [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW9)